# How can i get the source code after logging in with urlFetchApp?

Tags: google-apps-script, urlfetch

I am stucked. I can log in to the website and now after i logged in, i want to get the source code of the url2. Any ideas how i can continue here?

```
function login() {

 var url = "https://www.erevollution.com/en/login"; 
  var payload = {
    "email":"test@gmail.com", 
    "password":"testpassword",
    "remember":"on"
  }; 

  var options = {
    "payload":payload,
    "method":"post",
    "followRedirects" : false
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  if ( response.getResponseCode() == 200 ) {                                             //could not log in.
    var result = "Couldn't login. Username/password is incorrect.";
  } 
  else if ( response.getResponseCode() == 302 ) {                                        //login was successful
     var result = "Logged in successfully";

     var cookie = response.getAllHeaders()['Set-Cookie'];     
     var header = { "Cookie":cookie[0] };
     var options2 = { "headers": header };
     var url2 = "https://www.erevollution.com/tr/market/1/1/1/1";
     var response2 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url2, options2);   
  }
 Logger.log(result);
 Logger.log(response2);

}
```

Comment: you I need to urlfetch again the url with the cookie header

Comment: @TheMaster like this ? ```var sourcecode2 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url2, header);```

Comment: with this i get the source code of the website without login

Comment: Don't know whether you can get, but that's the way it's supposed to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by taking my response headers cookies and sorting them as the request headers cookies of the next page (`url2`) wanted. So i got the right order of cookie (`newcookie`) for the next page.

[image: Response Headers]
[image: Request Header]

```
function Price() {
 var url = "https://www.erevollution.com/en/login"; 
  var payload = {
    "email":"test@gmail.com", 
    "password":"testpassword",
    "remember":"on"
  }; 

  var options = {
    "payload":payload,
    "method":"post",
    "followRedirects" : false
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  if ( response.getResponseCode() == 200 ) {               //could not log in.
    var result = "Couldn't login. Username/password is incorrect.";
  } 
  else if ( response.getResponseCode() == 302 ) {         //login was successful
       var result = "Logged in successfully";
      var cookie = response.getAllHeaders()['Set-Cookie'];     

         for(m=0;m<5;m++){
          cookie[m]=cookie[m].substring(0,cookie[m].indexOf(";"));
         }
       var newcookie=cookie[4]+"; "+cookie[1]+"; "+cookie[2]+";"+cookie[3]+"; "+cookie[0];

       var header = { "Cookie":newcookie };
       var options2 = { "headers": header };


        var url2 = "https://www.erevollution.com/tr/market/1/1/1/1";
        var response2 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url2, options2);
        var content = response2.getContentText();
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Issue:

You should be including the cookie in the property `headers` of the object you are passing as parameter of your call, as you can see [in the docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl-params).

#### Code sample:

```js
var header = { "Cookie": cookie[1] };
var options = { "headers": header };
var url = "https://www.erevollution.com/tr/market/1/1/1/1";
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
```

#### Reference:

- [UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl-params)

Comment: i updated now my current code, i try with `cookie[0]` ,`cookie[1]` and `cookie[2]` and i get as response only blank variable. these are my headers https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLexT.png and this is the log https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYoxH.png

Comment: and this are my headers when i am in ".../market/1/1/1/1" https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1bKE.png

Comment: @biber54 Have you used [getContentText()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response#getContentText()) on `response`?

Comment: @biber54 I cannot reproduce this. Also, there is a typo in your code. You are declaring `var options2 = { "headers": header };`, and then passing `options` to the fetch: `var response2 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options); `. You should pass `options2` instead.

Comment: @biber54 Could you test this?

Comment: yes i tested this but i solved it by sorting the cookies. i posted the answer below